# Do adjectives have to be plural for a singular "vous"?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, pluriel, accord, vouvoiement

Since vous can refer to a plural subject as well as a formal singular subject, I'm wondering whether adjectives need to always treat it as plural.

So is the following correct, if the subject is formal singular?

> Vous êtes allergique aux chats.

Or does it have to be:

> Vous êtes allergiques aux chats.

--even though the subject is singular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The adjectives in this case follow notional or semantic, not purely grammatical agreement. The verb goes in the plural, but the adjectives go in the singular.